# Accessing Marvell switch via remote management interface

Tags: switch, ethernet

I have 88E6341 Marvell Ethernet switch.

I cannot access its MDIO and according to the datasheet the switch has remote management via Ethernet which I'm interested to use to diagnose connectivity issues.

What SW tools can I use on Windows or Linux to access switch registers?

Comment: [did you read the manual?](https://www.marvell.com/content/dam/marvell/en/public-collateral/transceivers/marvell-phys-transceivers-alaska-88e151x-datasheet.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi23t-r5K_3AhVU7rsIHS-tDboQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw1KSaQfhyQ6L9r0r-GoIluF)

Comment: @djdomi Yes, I did. It says there is remote management interface but nothing about how to generate the management Ethernet frames. BTW your link URL is broken, what resource are you referring?

Comment: i was linking to the manual, but it seems that they use non static links. Sadly. I do not get the point what you try to solve. this is just a simple enduser switch with basic, limited use cases